# Count Even Digits in an Integer in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to write a method in Java that will return true if an integer only consists of even digits.

For example when the input integer is 2468, the  method will return true. 
Another example, if the input integer is -68, the method will return true. If the integer consisted of 24638, the method should return false.

I also am trying to use only integers. I do not want to use ToString() to take the length of the integer as my condition in my loop and I also do not want to use an array.

I have searched the forums but most replies seem to use ToString() or arrays of which I’m avoiding. 
My code is below:

```
int countEven = 0;
int countOdd = 0;
if (n == 0)
    countEven++;
while (n != 0)  {
    int lastdigit = n % 10;
    if (lastdigit == 0 || lastdigit % 2 == 0)
        countEven++;
    else
        countOdd++;
    n = n /10;
}
if (countEven >= 0); return true;
```

Comment: So you have some code - you should describe what exactly is wrong about it.

Comment: You have a semicolon after the `if` before the return. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Note that you should drop that `if` altogether: `return countEven >= 0;`

Comment: `if (countEven >= 0); return true; ` - mistake, empty if body. To prevent this always enclose the block into `{}` even it consists of one statement

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko Adding braces wouldn't prevent this mistake - the code would continue compiling.

Comment: Should your return not be `return countOdd == 0`? From what I understood your idea.
Also where is your question?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight correct, but with braces it would become obvious that there is a flaw in the code. Moreover IDE would highlight that method lacks return statement `if (countEven >= 0) { ; return true; }`

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko Oh, I'm pretty sure OP put that semicolon to "fix" the "no return" error. The very same mistake is possible with curly braces: `if (countEven >= 0) ; { return true; }`

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback and suggestions. I am new to java and Stack Overflow. In the future I will be more detailed with my question. Also 
TMcSquared suggestion below solved the problem I was experiencing.

Answer (score 5):

You are not checking the condition for `countodd`. Lets say number is 235. Your `counteven` will be 1 and `countodd` will be 2. Then your last if condition will return `true` no matter what. Instead try this,

```
while(n != 0){
    int lastdigit = n % 10;
    if(lastdigit % 2 == 1)
        return false;
    n = n /10;
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your last if statement is not correct.

Try this:

```
if (countOdd > 0)
    return false;
else
    return true;
```